# How to Implement a collection that supports add O(1), remove max O(logn) and vice versa?

Tags: java, performance, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I need to implement 2 collections that support:

1. Add(int) with O(1) and Remove_max() with O(logn)
2. Add(int) with O(logn) and Remove_max() with O(1)

I did some math and figured that if any of the collections exists i can sort N numbers with O(log(n!) + O(N)) which contradicts the lower bound for sorting which is O(N*log(N)).

Am i wrong?

Comment: This topic sounds more suitable for https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt:  Algorithm discussion is totally on-topic here.

Comment: Implementation of algorithms but the op asks about the existence of an algorithm that has a better complexity of sorting than the known nest-complexity algorithm. That's not a programming question

Comment: @emdshx We can if you can compensate memory for speed, if you do a bucket sort.

Comment: I believe a heap will give you the second behavior, still thinking about the first.

Comment: For Case#2 you can keep your collection sorted by inserting new elements with binary search.

Comment: Also the very formula of `O(...) + O(...)` does not make any sense.

Comment: Yes, @PM77-1, but then one must be careful to choose a data structure for which the insertion itself does not dominate the cost.  An array won't do, for example.

Comment: @JohnBollinger For O(1) insertions or deletions, LinkedList will work, but for searching it won't scale.

Comment: @PM77-1 - in that case, we use the one which dominates runtime.  I'd imagine that O(log(n!)) would dominate *pretty* quickly over O(n) anyway.

Comment: How do you figure that `O(long(n!))` is less than `O(n log(n))`?

Comment: @Makoto - Yes, this was my point exactly.

Comment: @JohnBollinger:  [I decided to graph it.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+log(n!)+from+1+to+1000,+n+from+1+to+1000)   n! does not *play*.

Comment: @PM77-1 you might be right about the formula, but if i use binary search when inserting can i still support removing max with O(1)? a balanced tree / heap wont work!

Comment: @JohnBollinger n! < n^n => log(n!) < log(n^n) = n*log(n)

Comment: If you keep your collection sorted - position of the max element would be deterministic.

Comment: @PM77-1 which ds supports what you say?

Answer (score 1):

Complete rewrite of the first case:

The first case--it may work to keep in a heap-tree sorted with the SMALLEST at the top.  I'm not sure, but if you started with the lowest on the top you might be able to always ensure that of the two children, the larger child contained the branch that contained the largest number.. then when removing you would just have to recurse down following the larger of the two children until you hit a leaf.

I haven't thought this through completely or tried it, but if there is a way to do it, this is the only style I can imagine.

The second one is pretty much the definition of a heap.  The largest item is always at the top of the tree (which will be O(1) to remove and replace with the next biggest of it's two children).  Adding to it is about the speed of a binary tree search because you would have to traverse down to a branch where the parent is larger than the value you are adding and the child is smaller....

Hmm, if it got unbalanced it would degrade into a linked list which would be O(n)…  I suppose some smarts about where you placed new items in the tree or dynamic rebalancing would be in order--but any tree structure can get unbalanced and degrade to O(n).

Comment: a heap doesn't support delete max/min with O(1), you need to fix the heap with swift-down/up which takes O(logn)

Comment: He didn't ask for min, only max--but it's probable I'm missing something.

Comment: @Gox I think you are right.  I was trying to figure out if it could be balanced (as much as possible) as you build it (Everything on the left is always larger than everything on the right or something strange like that) but I couldn't work through the details without coding it up.  Yeah, that wouldn't work--but if there is a solution it has to be something like that.

Comment: ok edit your answer so i can delete mine

Answer (score 1):

Use a HashSet, which has O(1) for both operations.

O(1) is better than O(log n) and this would pass any test for being O(log n), because time complexity is an *upper* bound (not a specific time), so by definition O(1) satisfies being O(log n).

Comment: good one :) i was not thinking about it

Comment: A HashSet won't work for RemoveMax unfortunately.

Comment: removing the max would cost to rescan the whole set with O(n) to find out the next max